# Euler function and cardinality

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $\phi$ denote Euler's totient function, and let $d$ denote the divisor function.

1. For $n \geq 1$, let $S_n = \{ \phi(1),...,\phi(n) \}$. Is there a formula for $|S_n|$ in terms of $n$?
2. For $n \geq 1$, let $T_n = \{ \phi(1)^1,...,\phi(n)^n \}$. Is there a formula for $|T_n|$ in terms of $n$?
3. For $n \geq 1$, let $R_n = \{ \phi(1)^{d(1)},...,\phi(n)^{d(n)} \}$. Is there a formula for $|R_n|$ in terms of $n$?

Comment: 1. This is [A061070](https://oeis.org/A061070). 2. This is clearly $n-1$.

Comment: Why is it clear that (2) is $n - 1$?

Comment: @LSpice Ah, sorry, thinking more my argument does not work, and it's not actually clear at all that 2 is $n-1$ (it's been a long day...). In fact, it's false, and seems only to be true for $1 \leq n \leq 101$. After that, it seems to be $n-2$ for a while, at least.

Comment: Regarding 2), it seems noteworthy that the pair $(m,n)$ responsible for the ``drop" (i.e., for which $\phi(m)^m = \phi(n)^n$) consists of products of (2 or) Fermat primes, namely $m=85 = 5\cdot 17$ and $n=102=2\cdot 3\cdot 17$, giving a $2$-power as the common value  $\phi(m)^m = \phi(n)^n = 2^{510}$. There is indeed no further collision among values $n\le 10^6$, and there might not be any more at all. Proving such a thing would probably be very hard - maybe it could be possible to construct further examples conditional on the (not-so-likely) availability of suitable large Fermat primes?!